# An offline desktop app with Electron alongwith Indexeddb and Fuse OSx

Tags: electron, atom-editor, desktop-application, indexeddb, fuse

I'm new to Electron and Fuse OSx, and would like to build a desktop app which can be used in offline (I'll be storing the data in indexeddb). How to bring the Fuse module inside an Electron desktop app. Is there any possiblities to achieve my case. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Definitely sounds like you'll need [native modules](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules).

Comment: @JohnWeisz Is there any demo app which could help me to go through the code base? And I've forgotton to mention that desktop app will be having a sync option when the user comes to online. Will Fuse help me to solve my case? Or for syncing I should use any other modules?